# Preventing duplicate entries from online profile form

Tags: profile, duplicate-contacts

We currently have an online profile form in place where new charity members complete their details - This then creates a new charity group on Civi.

We are having instances where new members are entering their details multiple times, which then creates multiple instances of the same group on Civi.

Is there a away to stop multiple groups being created, such as making Civi / The form check for duplicate entries that are already present on the system.
Such as check if the email address is already in use for example?

Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have an unsupervised dedupe rule setup for individuals. This is used to check if a contact is already in the dB when they complete a form as an anonymous (not logged in) user. The default unsupervised rule is to match email. You can create a new one that looks at other fields. It is important that all the fields used in your unsupervised rule are in the profile used.

Also, you may want to look at the advanced settings in your profile setup. There are options there with what to do with duplicate contacts.

There is some more info about the dedupe rule types here:
https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/common-workflows/deduping-and-merging/#understanding-dedupe-rules-supervised-unsupervised-and-general

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for this thats great - Ive setup an unsupervised rule to match a couple of the fields and it is working brilliantly :) Thanks again, Terry